# Loading a JSON-Array fails

Tags: java, android, json

The JSON-String/Array I get as HTTP-Response is in a single line, like this:

```
[{
        "haendlerName": "Zielpunkt",
        "shops": [{
            "shopId": 243779,
            "ort": "Wien",
            "strasse": "Erdbergstraße 61",
            "plz": "1030",
            "lat": 48.19867,
            "lon": 16.400263,
            "distance": 0.14937061106081023,
            "openinghours": null
        }],
        "imageLink": "http://images.schnapp.at/images/zielpunkt__e349e2a937b5bf4f78e0fb3063b1fca8.png",
        "account_id": 171619
    }, ...
```

I´m loading it like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity(); 
String response2=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(response2);
```

EDIT: WORKING VERSION!

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);    
response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
finalResult = new JSONArray(json);
```

But in the very last line it crashes, only error I got is a NullPointerException.
I checked to content of the tokener, seems to be fine.
Also checked to whole input (the String from http-response), it´s a valid JSON-string.

What might be worth mentioning is that the JSONObjects in the main-array also contain a sub-array.

Any Idea what might cause the crash? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `BufferedReader`, `String json` and `JSONTokener tokener`. the try this way

```
String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(json);
```

`EntityUtils.toString` reads the content of the `Entity` and returns it as `String`

you should replace:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String json = reader.readLine();
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
    JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
```

with

```
String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(json);
```

Comment: @BenjaminSchwalb Crashes? how do you get the json by making a http request?

Comment: `response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String json = reader.readLine();`

Comment: Try this `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)`

Comment: If it crashes on the "first" row (mine I suppose), it means that response is null

Comment: `JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(_response);`
With this i guess? Doesnt work either

Comment: as @blackbelt suggests your response might be null. check if response==null and log something.

Comment: response is "org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@41edaef0"

Comment: the response is not a json.

Comment: I´d love to read the stackTrace aswell, but I can´t catch the exception - not even catch(Exception e) works

Comment: `HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity(); 
String response2=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);`
response2 (=your _response) is json:
"[{"haendlerName":"Bauhaus","shops":[{"shopId":237869,"ort":"Wien","strasse":"Wagramer Straße 196","plz":"1220","lat":48.253773,"lon":16.446697,"distance":0.09308023651533356,"openinghours":null}],"imageLink":"http://images.schnapp.at/images/Bauhaus_9b5d16f172baca19c2b65f059e1b256a.png","account_id":154679},..."

Comment: you have to replace   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String json = reader.readLine();
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
    JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener); with the code I posted

Comment: updated code, but still doesnt work.
also tried to make a JSONObject from json, doenst work either

Comment: Do you get always NullPointerException ?

Comment: to be clear when you say "last line" you mean JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(json); ?

Comment: yes - i get the normal "source not found", and e is a NullPointerException, can´t find anything else

Comment: without the stacktrace I am clueless . The only thin that could be null is the String json. Can you try to print it (with Log.i for instance)?

Comment: That´s it, valid json: [{"haendlerName":"Bauhaus","shops":[{"shopId":237869,"ort":"Wien","strasse":"Wagramer Straße 196","plz":"1220","lat":48.253773,"lon":16.446697,"distance":0.09308023651533356,"openinghours":null}],"imageLink":"http://images.schnapp.at/images/Bauhaus_9b5d16f172baca19c2b65f059e1b256a.png","account_id":154679},{"haendlerName":"Eurospar","shops":[{"shopId":244129,"ort":"Wien","strasse":"Wagramer Straße 171","plz":"1220","lat":48.255863,"lon":16.44757,"distance":0.21927437351696688,"openinghours":null}],"imageLink":... (cut because too long for comment)

Comment: then it is impossible  you are getting a NPE from JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(json); . Are you sure it is a NPE and not another kind of Exception ?

Comment: yes, that´s what i says for e, also says that the activity was stopped because of a runtimeexception (if that is of any use)

Comment: can you copy and past the whole runtime exception ?

Comment: OMG i solved it - big fail on my side: 
i had `JSONArray finalResult` in my class (a Callable) and then called `JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(json);`, recreating an existing variable, changed to `finalResult = ..." and it works.
Thanks a lot for your effort!